# Problem with taxonomy and URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I can't find a way how to get correct URL. Situation :
Lets imagine i have a webpage with 3 tabs/menu entries (views) with titles A , B and C. 
Of course i have created  taxonomy vocabulary (lets say named : article_type) with 3 terms A,B,C .

Pattern for all Basic page : [current-page:title]/[node:title] // everything works fine (Page titles are A,B,C) ;

Pattern for Article path : [node:field_article_type]/[node:title] ;

Lets say I create article and choose in tax term A or  B or C , everything is fine ! URL www.example.com/A or B or C/ title of article , but if I want to assign article to not one but 2 or all 3 tax terms (pages) at the same time I am getting a problem with url because it look like : www.example.com/A+B+C/title of article whenever I am in tab A or in tab b or c. So what I need to change in article path to get correct URL path every time?

any other ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do you not have a token with term depth? Failing this you can use path auto's API (http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21pathauto%21pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_pattern_alter/7) and programmatically set your alias.